# dataframe vs data.frame tags which should be master?

Tags: discussion

Currently dataframe and data.frame both exist as tags, yet are obviously synonyms.

Given that dataframe has more questions under it, I'd be inclined to make that master, but on the other hand data.frame might be more clearly the thing in R.

Is it reasonable to suggest both? (I'd be disinclined unless that was the expected behaviour in such cases)

Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: The term 'data frame' is used in R help, while `data.frame` is the name of a command, so I would go for the first option which is probably more meaningful in terms of data structure.

Comment: @chi Okay, easy. I will go with the first option, thanks. ... edit: actually, I won't, as I just realized I don't have enough reputation in that tag to try.

Comment: [tag:dataframe] is irrelevant on this site because it appears intended to refer a *software-specific* construct, not to a general concept of statistics or data analysis. Arguably, *any* question for which this is an essential tag needs to be migrated away.  (If you think otherwise, how would you feel about having, say, a tag "struct" for people with C-oriented questions or a tag "common" for those with Fortran-oriented questions? These would seem to function in comparable roles; only the programming environment has changed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have converted all occurrences of `data.frame` to [dataframe](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataframe). These two tags are now synonyms.

Comment: Thanks very much chi

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have already been settled, but I wanted to voice an additional justification for the `data.frame` -> `dataframe` canonicalization: R is not the only language with a "dataframe" data structure. In python, there is `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: +1; This is the right argument and right way to build a consensus.